# Swift Add arrow and sourceView to UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController and I am trying to add an arrow to it and change the sourceView to self.button so it does not appear at the bottom.

This is what I got so far:

```
let dropdown = UIAlertController(title: "Select Room", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let kitchen = UIAlertAction(title: "Kitchen", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
        dropdown.addAction(kitchen)

        let livingRoom = UIAlertAction(title: "Living Room", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
        dropdown.addAction(livingRoom)

        let bedroom = UIAlertAction(title: "Bedroom", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
        dropdown.addAction(bedroom)

        let bathroom = UIAlertAction(title: "Bathroom", style: .Default) { (action) in
        }
        dropdown.addAction(bathroom)

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        }
        dropdown.addAction(cancel)

        dropdown.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        dropdown.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.dropdownButton.frame
        dropdown.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.dropdownButton
        dropdown.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Up

        self.presentViewController(dropdown, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But the arrow does not appear and the UIAlertController still appears at the bottom. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only get the arrow on an iPad. On an iPhone, it is always full screen with no arrow.

Answer (score 0):

`popoverPresentationController` (and it's settings) are meant to be used by a `UIViewController` who's `presentationStyle` is `UIModalPresentationPopover`.

While `UIAlertController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, it is special and uses `UIModalPresentationCustom` as it's `presentationStyle`. Attempts to set a new `presentationStyle` are ignored.

I don't think what you are trying to do is an intended use for `UIAlertController`. You best bet is to make your own view controller to achieve this purpose.